# using the dd command to copy 'broken' disk

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I have got an external seagate harddisk, used for backup. Now I can't enter the disk (not used dd command yet!). When I plugged it to a Windows computer, it said the disk needed to be formatted before it could be accessed, a linux running ubuntu 12.04 can't mount it, though I can find it if I use `hwinfo --disk` in the terminal. A friend told me about the dd command in linux, and I know it's risky (if you put input as output and output as input data is lost). I tried "dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb" and got "access denied", so I guess nothing has been overwritten at least. sdc is the seagate disk according to hwinfo and diskhandling manager installed at ubuntu, and sdb is an internal disk with same capacity, just empty. any ideas of what I should do to restore my data (if dd is able to)? or is the disk just too damaged to recover?

Answer (score 1):

You need root permissions to read from or write to a raw hard disk. So you would need to run

`sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb`

That being said, `dd` will create a raw copy of the disk with all its partition, bit by bit. It will not repair anything – however, it is a good idea to copy the data from the damaged disk to a good one using the above command, and then try to repair the copy of the data. That way, if something goes wrong and your rescue attempts end up doing more damage, you still have the original of the bad data and can make a fresh copy.

When you have cloned your bad disk that way, unplug it. Then you can start the actual recovery on the copy. One tool is `fsck`, which you can run in the following way (agagn, you need to be root):

`sudo fsck /dev/sdb1`

`/dev/sdb1` would be the first partition of your disk. If you have more than one partition, repeat the same for `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb3` and so on.

There is no guarantee that this will recover any data – but if not, it will give you a hint of the kind of damage and where to look further.

Comment: IMO it is best to write to a file and dd is not the best tool. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Imaging_a_damaged_device.2C_filesystem_or_drive

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, it started copying. But it's rather slow and I read I can set how much it should read/write at a time, but I'm not sure about this. Can you please show me how?

Comment: That's the `bs` parameter. E.g. `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdb bs=1024` will read 1024 bytes at a time. You can also use values like `1K` or `1M`. As for performance, you will need to experiment which value works best for you. Try this on a limited amount of data – e.g. `count=1024` to copy 1024 blocks of the specified size – and look at the data transfer rate. Then try to find the `bs=` setting which gives you the highest transfer rate.